# PHP "Save as..." file

Tags: php

I want to allow users to download a specific file from the server and let them choose the name of the file.

It is a JSON file.

I have the following PHP script that works but it is naming the file automatically:

```
if (file_exists($myFile)){
    header ("Content-Type: application/download");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$myFile");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize("$myFile"));
    $fp = fopen("$myFile", "r");
    fpassthru($fp);
} else {
    echo "no file exists";
};
```

Comment: It entirely depends on the browser to give the user a choice of name or to save it with the "default" name. You can't really do anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers open that save as dialog depending on the content-type.
Within the browser a user can specify which mime-type should open in which way.

btw. normally you specify for json the mime type  `application/json` - see RFC 4627

you could try to set the type to `application/octet-stream`.

but as i wrote - it depends on user settings.

In firefox it can be modified this way:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$myFile");` to be `header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$chosenFileName");` where $chosenFileName is the name provided by the user.

Comment: Hi, that's the idea, but the $chosenFileName should be provided in a dialog box when the user clicks the button that runs this script

Comment: That's a rather awkward solution. Browsers have their own *save-as* dialogs, and this solutions creates another *save-as* dialog. That means that users who set their browser to download a file automatically - that is, users who **don't** want to see the *save-as* dialog - will see your version of that dialog, while users who set their browser to show a *save-as* dialog will see **two** *save-as* dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Step - 1 . First when click on download button open a form with input filename (open popup or another page its upon you)

Step - 2 Now give the name of file (I mean enter name in text box and click on submit);

Step - 3 On submit send request as a post (method = 'POST') to the download file.
          this look like $_POST['filename'];

Step - 4

```
if($_POST['filename']){
    $filename = $_POST['filename']; 
}

if (file_exists($myFile)){
    header ("Content-Type: application/download");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename ");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize("$filename "));
    $fp = fopen("$filename ", "r");
    fpassthru($fp);
} else {
    echo "no file exists";
};
```

I hope this will help you ..!!